# Are Azure Web Applications subject to resource restrictions from Application Service Plans they don't belong to?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, quota, azure-app-service-plans

I have one Resource Group. In it:

- I have two Web Applications (A and B).
- I have two Application Service Plans (PlanA and PlanB).
- Each Web Application is alone in its Application Service plan. (A in PlanA, B in PlanB)

Both A and B consume between 1 and 9 GB of disk space each.

- When I set both PlanA and PlanB to level B1, both A and B run fine.
- When I stop the service for B, A continues to run fine, and B is shut down.
- When I scale PlanB down to the Free level (and thus exceed its quota), B does not run.

However - Web App A (which is running in Service Plan PlanA) throws out of disk errors. These errors go away when I change PlanB back to B1. I thought the whole idea of Application Service Plans was to separate resource consumption between groups of applications. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought the whole idea of Application Service Plans was to separate resource consumption between groups of applications.

Firstly, the resource group is just a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. It is used to easily manage your resources and deploy. The service plan in the resource group will not affect another service plan.

Secondly, the service plan will not affect another service plan. Each service plan use its own physical server resources.

Besides, an app in App Service can be associated with only one App Service plan at any given time.

So the plan B will not affect the plan A.

I guess there maybe another reason causes the plan A web app show disk error.

I suggest you could firstly check the quota of your web app to make sure there are enough disk space to run your wen app. More details about how to check it, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2017/06/06/azure-app-service-what-is-taking-my-disk-space-for-my-azure-web-app/).

If the service plan has enough disk and still show this error. I suggest you could try to scale up the service plan A then scale down.

Comment: Have you check the quota as my answer shows? Does your web app A exceed the quota? I suggest you recheck your web app A make sure it run in the service plan A not B.

Comment: That's how I thought it should be. Fact is, when I scaled Plan B down, App A through disk quota errors - both in running applications and in FTP file uploads. When I scaled Plan B back up - the disk quota errors went away and the FTP worked again. Repeatedly.

Tonight, I deleted App Service B. It said since there were no other services using Plan B, it would remove that too. I confirmed. App B and Plan B were deleted. App A immediately failed. To get App A running again, I needed to create a brand new Service Plan (C) and move App A to C. It worked, and I deleted Plan A.

Comment: I checked that App A and Plan A were paired and App B and Plan B were paired with 2 different sets of eyes three times. App B and Plan B were created months and months after App A and Plan A were put into service.

App A did not exceed quota for Plan A at any time. 20% usage. App A DID exceed quota for Plan B, when things were scaled.

Except for the fact that I have to do a similar migration in another environment this week, I'm counting it as a freak config occurrence that has been fixed by deleting.

Comment: In my opinion, this may be related with server side. The workaround is you could create plan C and move web A to plan C. Besides, if you still want to know why show this error, I suggest you could try to connect to azure support team to check the server service plan.

Comment: Thanks. The problem didn't re-occur when I did it in the other environment.

I'm going to mark your answer as correct. App Service plan quotas *shouldn't* impact each other. Mine just somehow did. :)